# Include and access binary (non-Java) files in an Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to include some binary not Java-related files in my Eclipse plugin, so I can access them later from within the Java code of the plugin.

1)
As far as I understand I can add some files and folders to include in a build in the "Build / Binary Build" section of the Build Configuration:

[image]

Unfortunately the folder "folder-to-include" and all files beneath are not copied to the "bin" folder (or anywhere else) after building the plugin. Did I misunderstand that dialog? I always thought of the "bin" folder as the "root" of the built project / plugin. What is the proper way to include binary files in the build?

2) If I managed to include my files in the built plugin, how do I determine the path to them so I can open and work with them in one of the Java classes of the plugin?

Comment: How are you building the plug-in? Everything you check should be included at the top level of the jar. Also you don't have plugin.xml checked - which is an important file.

Comment: @greg-449 I use the builtin "build project" functionality which compiles all Java files to .class ones and copy them together with some plugin metadata to the bin folder (this is how it looks for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you check in the build should be included in the plug-in jar at the top level (the `bin` directory is handled specially).

To find an object in a plug-in use:

```
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path(path), null);
```

where `path` is a relative path in the plug-in and `bundle` is the plug-in `Bundle`. You can get the `Bundle` from the `BundleContext` passed to the plug-in activator or by using `Platform.getBundle("plugin id")`

The URL returned from this will use the `bundle` scheme, to convert it to a `file` URL use:

```
URL fileURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
```

The file URL returned may be in a temporary location.

Update: When you run your plug-in from with Eclipse (with Run / Eclipse Application) then no jar is built and the folders are not copied anywhere. You still use the `FileLocator` API to access the folders and the paths are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately no jar is built at all if I build or run/debug my plugin. Do I have to bundle my plugin within a JAR to have the files copied? Afaik I do not have to build a jar from my plugin in order to use it - just as it doesn't build one when running/debugging it.

Comment: Updated answer with details about running during testing in Eclipse